# Bundle Install failed due to : Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I am a newbie to ruby language and I'm trying to run an existing ruby on rails project. While am trying to run `bundle install` it fails with the following error.

```
Fetching mysql2 0.4.6
Installing mysql2 0.4.6 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/vince/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.6/ext/mysql2
/home/vince/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/ruby -I /home/vince/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20221031-7332-kotkbi.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for rb_big_cmp()... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/vince/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-ruby-dir
        --without-ruby-dir
        --with-ruby-include
        --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
        --with-ruby-lib
        --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysqlclient-dir
        --without-mysqlclient-dir
        --with-mysqlclient-include
        --without-mysqlclient-include=${mysqlclient-dir}/include
        --with-mysqlclient-lib
        --without-mysqlclient-lib=${mysqlclient-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
/home/vince/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `block in find_library': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /home/vince/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `collect'
        from /home/vince/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `find_library'
        from extconf.rb:95:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/vince/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/mysql2-0.4.6/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vince/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vince/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/mysql2-0.4.6/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.6' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

The ruby version is **2.7.6** , Rails **5.0.7.2**, Environment **Ubuntu 20.04**

Does anyone know the cause of the issue and how it can be solved? I have tried with diffrent stack overflow answers and none of them helped.

Please let me know if you need any further details.

thank you.

Comment: Does `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.6' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeed?

Comment: @ChaseMcDougall No, It returns the same error.

Comment: Have you looked at https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/error-occurred-while-installing-mysql2/76210/3? Seems to have the same issue which resulted from MySQL not being installed locally.

Comment: It doesn't worked.

Comment: Get the contents of /home/vince/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/mysql2-0.4.6/gem_make.out 

(The log file after the install fails)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to install `mysql` first via brew

```
brew install mysql
```

Then try to install the gem

```
gem install mysql2
```

After succeedd, please run `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the perfect answer, However, it solves my issue.

Changed the mysql2 version in the gem file as follows

```
gem 'mysql2', '~>0.5.4'
```

Then run `bundle install` solved my issue.